# Ejecutar doble consulta sql con una función php Mysql

Tags: php, sql

Estoy tratando de realizar doble consulta o ejecutar dos códigos SQL en una función.

Les explico: primeramente se genera una captura de información, digamos pre captura (módulo 1), desde otro módulo recupera dicha información y le agrega otros campos que completan la información (módulo 2), al darle guardar manda ciertos campos a la parte de venta (módulo 3), lo cual hace la función que aquí les muestro.

```php
public function registrar($foliofic, $nombre, $apellidopat, $apellidomat, $estatus, $vendedor, $telmarcado, $folioint, $celular, $producto, $upgrade, $adicional,  $seguro, $estatusfico, $validador, $fechaventa)
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO ventanueva (foliofico, nombre, apellidopat, apellidomat, estatusvta, vendedor, telmarcado, folioint, celular, producto, upgrade, ventaadic,  ventaseg, estatusfico, validador, fechaventa) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $array = array($foliofic, $nombre, $apellidopat, $apellidomat, $estatus, $vendedor, $telmarcado, $folioint, $celular, $producto, $upgrade, $adicional,  $seguro, $estatusfico, $validador, $fechaventa); 
        return $this->insertar($sql,$array);
    }
```

La primera función trabaja bien sola, sin embargo lo quiero es correr una segunda consulta la cual me cambie un valor de otra tabla (módulo 1)

```php
$sql = "UPDATE ventapend SET activa = 0 WHERE id=?";
$array = array($id);
return $this->save($sql,$array);
```

Comment: El código y la explicación no son muy detallados, ¿el `$id` del update de dónde sale? ¿de la inserción que haces en la primera consulta?

Comment: El id se obtiene del módulo 1..  cuando se genera la precaptura se genera el ID para este.

Comment: Por favor no uses términos no relevantes ni explicaciones que no ayudan en el problema (módulo1,2,3, precaputas ¿?) mantén simple la explicación del problema

Comment: Ok disculpa... primero realizo una captura de información el cual le asigna su propio y único ID, posteriormente se recupera esa información y agregan otros campos para completar la info. Lo que ya hace es guardar la información completa en la tabla correspondiente. Pero quiero que en la primer tabla, donde hice la primer captura cambie el valor de la columna activa de 1 a 0